# Mod_rewrite - don't display certain query string in the url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I know this question may have been asked several times, but to be honest I haven't yet found a complete answer for this.

I have this url:
modelDetails.php?manufacturerName=$1&manfuacturerID=$2&modelName=$3&modelID=$4&yachtCode=$5&lang=$6

Is it possible not to display yachtCode and lang in the url and still pass the values from page to page?
This is my htacces file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(EN|DE|NL)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ modelDetails.php?manufacturerName=$1&manufacturerID=$2&modelName=$3&modelID=$4&yachtCode=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the data from the query string, then the only other way to access the data is to retrieve it from a cookie. But to set the cookie you'll have to have the yachtCode value appear in the query string at some point.

The only alternative would be to use POST (the mode used by a web form) instead of GET (the mode which is generally used). POST mode submits variables as part of the request, rather than adding the variables to the query string. But you can't force a hyperlink to use POST mode, so this is probably not of use to you.

In short, you probably can't hide yachtCode from the end user completely.